# How to find folders by name, then sort by size

Tags: shell, sorting

Apologies for what I'm sure is a frequently asked question in one of many permutations. I'm asking again however, because I didn't find the exact answer to my question so far.

**The goal: find all folders that contain the string "foo", then sort them by size (alternatively: instead of sorting, return only those folders that are larger than size N).**

Alternatively I could ask: How to sort the output of 'find' by size. (That exact question *was* already asked on Stackoverflow, but received no answer so far).

Here's what I tried already...

Return all folders larger than 100 MB. Doesn't work because folder size is always 0?

```
find / -iname "*foo*" -size +100M
```

Using output option '-ls' of find, then sort. Doesn't work either: it's sorted, but not by size.

```
find / -iname "*foo*" -ls | sort
```

Any help appreciated!

<strike>**EDIT: Think I just found the answer, in on of the related topics displayed on the right... Apologies again, I knew I should have searched more thoroughly :/**</strike>

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `find` with `stat` and `sort`:

```
find / -iname "*foo*" -type d -size +100M -exec stat -c '%n:%s' {} \; | sort -t: -k2,2 -rn | cut -d ':' -f1
```

Comment: Thanks :) Doesn't seem work though, maybe because I'm on OSX?

Comment: I am also on OSX. Just replace `stat -c '%n:%s'` by `stat -f '%N:%z'`. Final command: `find / -iname "*foo*" -type d -size +100M -exec stat -f '%N:%z' {} \; | sort -t: -k2,2 -rn | cut -d ':' -f1`

Comment: I could be wrong, but it seems that the '-size +N' leads to find returning not a single directory.

Comment: It could be because I am using `home brew` on my OSX and using gnu utilities. Try: `find / -iname "*foo*" -type d -exec stat -f '%N:%z' {} \; | sort -t: -k2,2 -rn | cut -d ':' -f1`

Answer (score 0):

```
find / -iname "*foo*" -type d -ls| sort -nk7
```

-n for numerical sort. -k7 is field on which to sort(use the number which contains size, 7 is in bash shell)

```
find . -iname "*foo*" -type d -ls|sort -nk7|sed "s/^[^:]*:[^\ ]*\ //g"
```

in case you need only names of folders

Comment: I'm seriously sorry for being so clueless about this, but it doesn't work. Just to be sure, in general: if I call 'ls -la', should I see the directory size? If so, it doesn't seem to happen when I use it.

Answer (score 0):

By the size of a folder you seem to understand the sum of the sizes of the files in it and probably all subdirectories of it. If so, `du` is best suited for the task.

```
du / | grep foo | sort -n
```